# Kubuntu 23.04 - screen freezes randomly when connected to external monitor (extand display)

Tags: multi-monitor, freeze, sleep

The weird thing is, that connecting to 2 external extended display monitors (viewing with 3 monitors including the laptop's one), and the problem does not happen.

Only with 1 monitor attached.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.04
Release:        23.04
Codename:       lunar
```

```
inxi -SGxc 0


System:
  Host: sza-ThinkBook-15-G4-IAP Kernel: 6.4.3-060403-generic arch: x86_64
    bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.4 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04
    (Lunar Lobster)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-12.2 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: USB C Video Adaptor type: USB driver: N/A bus-ID: 3-3.3.3:7
  Device-3: Luxvisions Innotech Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-5:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 resolution:
    1: 1920x1080~60Hz 2: 1920x1080~60Hz 3: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1 renderer: Mesa Intel
    Graphics (ADL GT2) direct-render: Yes
```

Please help, I don't know where to start to find the problem.

Another strange thing that happens, the computer stopped entering to sleep mode. stays awake. (it worked before.)
I don't know if the 2 problems are related to each other. (probably not).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Still having this issue. 
journalctl doesn't tells much.
Any ideas on where I might find a hint to the reason for it?